# How to fix the shock I was getting from my 3D printer?

Tags: grounding, shock

Our house do not have proper grounding, only hot and neutral wires are present. Now, every time I touch the chassis of my 3D printer it shocks me.

I tested the ac voltage between the chassis and the hot wire also from chassis to neutral wire and I get 100+ voltage. In my country we have 220V AC in our sockets.

Comment: Wire the house correctly. Chances are, someone flipped the hot and neutral in some locations to boot. If you want a patch in the mean time, move the power supply far away and run DC only to the printer. Remember to isolate the body of the power supply from anything you might touch.

Comment: @Abel That does not indicate hot and neutral being swapped. And if power supply output is commoned to ground inside the supply (like standard PC supplies) then isolating the supply body does not help as the output will be just as tingly.

Comment: And what does "to boot" indicate? If there's one bug that you find, there's likely many more that you do not find.

Comment: Sounds like Y-capacitor voltage divider to ground. Is your AC outlet grounded?

Comment: @Abel just having an old house with no grounding does not mean there is something incorrectly wired. Winny, the OP first said the house only has hot and neutral so obviously the AC outlet is not grounded, and yes it will be Y-cap leakage as said in answers.

Comment: The outlet is not grounded, the whole house is not grounded. Is a Y-cap leakage fixable or should I just leave it and use a slipper whenever I touch the printer?

Comment: Consider an "antistatic wrist strap".

Comment: @Kurisu Y-cap leakage is not a bug, it is a feature of the power supply, the power supply requires a grounded outlet, and if you don't have a grounded outlet, then you are using the power supply in a way it is not supposed to be used. Many appliances have a label that they must be connected to a grounded outlet for proper operation and safety. What you can do is to change the power supply to one that does not require ground, or come up with a properly grounded outlet.

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

Many power supplies require ground and if you don't have ground then all their grounded parts such as metal chassis will float at half mains AC voltage. This is due to filter caps from hot and neutral to chassis.

Which is proven by your measurement of having 100+ volts from chassis to neutral and hot wires.

Get an electrician. Those people know what to do and do it according to laws, regulations and electrical code used in your country. Do not try do it yourself, if you don't know what to do and how to do it safely and according to your local laws, regulations and electrical code.

Comment: If the answer is to "Get an electrician," and thus an "electrician" can, then logically "You can't" will only hold true if "You" can never become an "electrician." While it may apply to some, this makes the answer incorrect overall to the masses, at least some of which can become electricians.

Comment: @Abel Sure, technically it is possible to become an electrician and do it yourself, but it will be faster to just call someone else. It will take many months in training to be allowed to work on your own and have someone more experienced electrician to legally approve your work (they rarely want to be responsible for work done by someone else) or gaining experience even longer to be experienced enough to be legally able to approve your own work. Now is that feasible, it is unlikely, but possible.

Answer (score 2):

The printer likely has two low-value capacitors between hot and neutral wires and connected together to its chassis, but has no third wire for grounding OR you have no grounding in your outlet provided by the neutral wire. 
The two capacitors split the voltage in half between them, and that's why you find exactly half the voltage on your chassis. 
You haven't provided those details (2 or 3 contacts on your printer's power plug and whether you have neutral used as ground in your outlets?).

What you can do as a temporary measure is open up your outlet, connect the neutral wire to its ground contacts, thus using the neutral as a "ground". It's called "nulling" around here, but it is not recommended per regulations. It is still better than no grounding at all, but you need to have a good neutral.

Answer (score -1):

If it is just old wiring done correctly to old standards, the outlet should have a metal case that you can use like the third prong. This is why a lot of adapters for 2-prong outlets had a screw terminal that you could attach to that box. The conduit from that box should then go to some form of proper grounding, assuming the house's electricals don't have problems.

Old wiring may have other problems that should be figured out, hence less risk to involve a professional. There are many checks to be performed- making sure someone has not attempted "nulling" and resulted in a neutral or live case for what would normally be the third prong, that live/neutral are correct, connections to earth grounding (and checking that the earth grounding meets code), tracing these through the entire house so you don't get a surprise fire/breaker-blow when flipping on a lamp or light switch.

Another alternative, assuming you don't care to fix the house is to isolate your power supply. This should be easiest when it is physically moved far away from the printer.  In such a setup, the printer should only be getting low voltage DC wires coming in. The power supply does its shocking business elsewhere (maybe in a box far away that you never touch when it is powered for obvious safety reasons), where it will not affect you.

Comment: The OP said there are only live and neutral wires. So there is no ground coming to outlet metal case, assuming there even is a metal case. Sounds like you assume things are wired everywhere in the world like North America. Oh and many power supplies like desktop PCs connect the output negative/common to the metal case, so it will not help to move the power supply far away - so the low voltage DC wires will have the same 100+VAC common mode superimposed on them that shocks you. And in some parts of the world it is illegal to work on house mains wiring unless you are a qualified electrician.

Comment: Case connected to DC ground won't be an issue unless you attempt nulling or some other crazy combination method. The metal case's potential to live and neutral are of no consequence if you only bring in DC ground (aka metal case) and DC+ (some low voltage - 12,24,36 are common possibilities) that is relative to that ground. Live and neutral can be going to thousands of volts for all it matters as long as they are kept far enough to be inconsequential to the area where the user wishes not to be shocked (and the power supply handles whatever voltage they are).

Comment: The PSU mains input Y caps force the PSU earth input float at 100+VAC, PSU metal case and DC öutput common are connected to PSU earth, so both the PSU case and output and so anything powered by it will give shocks.